# using form rails in different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have views like this `"app/views/admin/index.html.haml"` , in this file I create

```
.container
  .d-flex.flex-column.justify-content-center
    = render partial: 'add_product'
```

I render another `partial` for creating the product

and i create another partial on admin directory `"app/views/admin/_add_product.html.haml"` :

```
.p-2
  .d.flex.flex-column.justify-content-center
    = form_for(@product) do |f|
      .form-group.row
        = f.label :name,  class: 'col-sm-2 col-form-label'
        %br/
        .col-sm-10
          = f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control'
```

on products controller `"app/controller/products_controller.rb"` :

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new product_values
  end

  private

  def product_values
    params.require(:product).permit(:name, :stock, :image, :price, :desc)
  end

end
```

so when I go to the route of "/admin", it seems "form" not created

it said: `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`
the problem is on `_add_product.html.haml`, it doesn't read the value of `@product` i created on the controller,

any idea how to use different views on controller ??

on my routes i did:

```
resources :products
```

Comment: So you're hitting `/admin`, where is the controller action for that? You need to define `@product` there.

Comment: can i not using contoller of admin for this , i want to use product controller to define this ??

Answer (score 0):

You have assign a value to `@product`.

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  # GET /admin
  def index
    @product = Product.new
  end
end
```

You can also do this in the partial itself by providing a default value:

```
= form_for(@product || Product.new) do |f|
```

Comment: got errror `uninitialized constant AdminController::Product`

Comment: That's strange, it does not make sense that Rails would fail to autoload the constant just because its in a different controller. Do you get a missing constant error if you explicitly reference it with `::Product.new`?

Comment: And at the risk of stating the obvious do you actually have a `Product` model?

Comment: that is true, i put like u said, but this way work ```= form_for :product, :url => {:controller => 'products', :action => 'create'} do |f|``` , i dont know why, is that correct syntax ??

Comment: That's really just the exact same as calling `form_for(@product)`.

Comment: i put that partial add_product in admin views, and i have another controller product, so is that correct way to use product controller in views in admin directory ?

Comment: i found on here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16430336/haml-form-for-rails

Comment: when i submit it doesnt work as well to follow that question link

Comment: I  answered my own question :D

Answer (score 0):

what another answer was almost correct but I forgot to create Model of `product.rb`
so I created that and then change on routes:

```
resources :products, controller: 'admin'
```

it solved my problem :D